# How to give a database constraint to ensure this behavior in a table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with five columns: A, B, C, D and E.

And I need to comply with the following restrictions:

- A is the primary key.
- For a B there can only be one C, ie: 1-1 ; 2-1 ; 3-2 but not 1-2.
- B-C and D can take any value but can not be repeated, ie: 1-1 1 ; 1-1 2 ; not 1-1 1 again.
- E can take any value.

So, considering the following order

```
| A | B | C | D | E |

| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | -> OK 

| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | -> Should fail, because there is a B with another C, 1-2 must be 1-1.

| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | -> OK

| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | -> Should fail, because relation between B-C and D is repeated.

| 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | -> OK
```

Is there any way to comply with this behavior through some constraint in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you consider triggers instead?

Comment: Sounds a lot like the structure is not normalized.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, but I would prefer not to use them in this case.

Comment: @DCookie Absolutely, but I can not refactor this table at this point in the project. It was already like this when I arrived ;)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz No, it's a real situation in a project in which I'm working on.

Comment: You can refactor a table at *any* point in a project. It just takes more planning and care at some points than at others.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' It's true what you say, but I need a palliative solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and E are irrelevant to the question and can be ignored.

The BCD rule can be easily solved by creating a unique index on BCD.

If for every B there can be only one C then your DB is not normalized. Create a new table with B and C. Make B the primary key or create a unique index on B. Then remove C from the original table. (At which point the unique index on BCD becomes a unique index on BD.)

Without normalizing the tables, I don't think there's any way to do it with a constraint. You could certainly do it with a trigger or with code.

Comment: I think you have given me the most accurate answer of all.
For the moment I will try to solve the problem using code.
Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For `B - C` rule I would create a trigger

For the `B - C - D` rule looks like you want unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT uni_BCD UNIQUE (B,C,D);
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition is not trivial

> > For a B there can only be one C, ie: 1-1 ; 2-1 ; 3-2 but not 1-2.

, since Oracle does not support `CREATE ASSERTION` (soon, we hope!)

Therefore, you need to involve a second table to enforce this constraint, or else a statement-level AFTER INSERT/UPDATE trigger.

What I would do is create a second table and have it maintained via an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on a view, and ensure all my application DML happened via the view.  (You could also just create a regular trigger on the table and have *it* maintain the second table.  That's just not my preference.  I find `INSTEAD OF` triggers to be more flexible and more visible.)

In case it's not clear, the purpose of the second table is that it allows you to enforce your constraint as a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.  The `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the second table ensures that each value of `B` appears only once.

Here's sample code for that approach:

```
--DROP TABLE table1_parent;
--DROP TABLE table1;


CREATE TABLE table1_parent
 ( b number NOT NULL,
   c number NOT NULL,
   constraint table1_parent_pk PRIMARY KEY (b),
   constraint table1_parent_u1 UNIQUE (b, c) );

CREATE TABLE table1
(
  a   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  b   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  c   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  d   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  e   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT table1_pk PRIMARY KEY (a),  -- "A is the primary key."
  CONSTRAINT table1_fk FOREIGN KEY ( b, c ) REFERENCES table1_parent ( b, c ), -- "For a B there can only be one C, ie: 1-1 ; 2-1 ; 3-2 but not 1-2."
  CONSTRAINT table1_u2 UNIQUE ( b, c, d ) -- "B-C and D can take any value bue can not be repeated, ie: 1-1 1 ; 1-1 2 ; not 1-1 1 again."
);

CREATE INDEX table1_n1 ON table1 (b,c); -- Always index foreign keys

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW table1_dml_v AS SELECT * FROM table1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_dml_v_trg INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON table1_dml_v
DECLARE
  l_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table1_parent (b, c) VALUES ( :new.b, :new.c );
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
        NULL;  -- parent already exists, no problem
    END;

    INSERT INTO table1 ( a, b, c, d, e ) VALUES ( :new.a, :new.b, :new.c, :new.d, :new.e );
  END IF;

  IF DELETING THEN
    DELETE FROM table1 WHERE a = :old.a;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_cnt FROM table1 WHERE b = :old.b AND c = :old.c;

    IF l_cnt = 0 THEN
      DELETE FROM table1_parent WHERE b = :old.b AND c = :old.c;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  IF UPDATING THEN
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table1_parent (b, c) VALUES ( :new.b, :new.c );
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
        NULL;  -- parent already exists, no problem
    END;

    UPDATE table1 SET a = :new.a, b = :new.b, c = :new.c, d = :new.d, e = :new.d WHERE a = :old.a;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_cnt FROM table1 WHERE b = :old.b AND c = :old.c;

    IF l_cnt = 0 THEN
      DELETE FROM table1_parent WHERE b = :old.b AND c = :old.c;
    END IF;

  END IF;      
END;


insert into table1_dml_v ( a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (1,1,1,1,1);
insert into table1_dml_v ( a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (2,1,2,1,1);
insert into table1_dml_v ( a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (3,1,1,2,1);
insert into table1_dml_v ( a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (4,1,1,2,1);
insert into table1_dml_v ( a,b,c,d,e) VALUES (5,2,1,1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your system supports fast refreshed materialized views, please try the following.
Since I currently don't access to a this feature, I can't verify the solution.

```
create materialized view log on t with primary key;

create materialized view t_mv
refresh fast
as
select      b,c
from        t
group by    b,c
;

alter table t_mv add constraint t_mv_uq_b unique (b);
```

and off course:

```
alter table t add constraint t_uq_a_b_c unique (b,c,d);
```